# 式を binary tree (二分木) で表したい

Tags: binary-tree

((A+B)*E)/(D-(C+F)%G)を[二分木](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-tree/)でどうしても表せません。特に、%Gの表し方に困っています。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

追記: %の優先順位が-よりも高いです。

Comment: プログラミング言語を1つに絞らないご質問でしょうか。何か特定のプログラミング言語を使った回答が欲しいということであれば、質問文に追記してください。

Comment: 二分木というか、構文木を作りたいということでしょうか。普通「算術式の二分木」などといった言い方はしないと思うので、どういう意味で「表し方」とおっしゃっているのかが知りたいです。参考になさっている資料へのポインタなどがあると良いです。

Comment: 図で表すことができたらと思います。例えば、以下のリンクの図を想定しています。https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-tree/

Comment: 分母に `-` と `%` がありますが、どちらの優先度の方が高いですか？（つまり、カッコをつけるとどうなりますか？）

Comment: ％の優先度が-よりも高いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問文にある式の構文木は、下図のようになります。`(D-(C+F)%G)` の部分は、省略されているカッコを演算子の優先順位を踏まえて復活させると `(D-((C+F)%G))` となることに注意してください。

[image: 構文木です]

Comment: ご多忙のところ、構文木を作成いただきありがとうございました。右半分の構造が自分では書けなかっただけに、とてもクリアになりました。

Comment: 後学のために、どういう部分が分からなかったのかを教えて頂けませんか？　`%`の左の子が `+` になるところでしょうか（でもこのパターンは分子にも登場しているので、どのあたりでつまづいていらっしゃったのかをはかりかねています）。

Comment: 仰る通りで、％の左の子がプラスになるところと、-の右の子が％になるところです。

Comment: なるほど、それでは優先順位を聞いたことが大きな意味になっていたのですね。ありがとうございます。　／　別件ですが、もしよろしければ回答を承認していただけると僕が嬉しいです。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: 初心者で勝手がわからず申し訳ございません。解答承認いたしました。引き続きどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。